# A movie where a man's bed dumps him into a pool of plasma

Tags: story-identification, movie

I prob saw the movie in the late 80s on TV. My recollection is that had the production quality of the late 70s.

The scene I remember has a man waking up in a bed with a woman. He pushes some button(s) on the bed's headboard (or perhaps uses a remote) and the room opens up like a garage door while the bed begins to move towards the opening. (I feel like it might have been established earlier that the bed would raise up and dump the occupant into a swimming pool.)

But as the bed gets closer to the pool outside, the man realizes it is full of some kind of glowing plasma instead of water. He tries to escape, but the woman restrains him and they are both dumped into the pool and vaporized.

Later we see some men toss a wreath into the now-empty pool, but I have no idea whether they were commemorating the death of the man, or the woman, who was seemingly a suicide-assassin of some kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably the second *Matt Helm* movie [*Murderers' Row*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060728/) (1966).  Matt is a supposedly retired spy who used to work for ICE; he has a bed that can slide into the next room and tip him into his pool-sized bathtub.

[image: Matt Helm and guest have a bath]
(Note: picture from the first movie; I haven't found a good picture from *Murderers' Row*.)

> Having just begun a thorough examination of Miss January's greatest attractions and about to enter the legendary Port city of Duluth, MN, Matt notices that **Miss January has pressed the button on his bed's control panel that causes it to take him for his morning plunge.**
>
> Matt quickly figures out that she is there in the capacity to terminate him.
>
> **The Super Helio Beam is waiting there to send Matt into the afterlife.**
>
> Miss January attempts to jump to safety leaving her would-be lover Matt to meet his doom.
>
> Miss January tries to jump out of bed to avoid the death ray, However, Helm tightens his grip on her and keeps her from escaping. Matt seems to have a confused look on his face. It's not clear if he realizes the true danger of his situation or not. It is clear that Miss January who was openly seducing him a few moments before is now trying to exit his bed posthaste.
>
> **The audience watches as the bed lifts off and we presume that the two slide into the water. All we see is that the beam goes off and there is a large explosion and light coming from the bath. Matt Helm is presumed dead, and ICE throws him a funeral.**

I found the described scene on YouTube:

In case the video is taken down, here are a few notable screenshots:

Matt Helm and Miss January are fooling around in bed:
[image: Matt Helm and Miss January are fooling around in bed]

Miss January fiddles with the buttons:
[image: Miss January fiddles with the buttons]

The bed starts to dump them into the pool:
[image: The bed starts to dump them into the pool]

The Helio Beam is firing into the pool:
[image: The Helio Beam is firing into the pool]

The bed dumps them and the Helio Beam fries them:
[image: The bed dumps them and the Helio Beam fries them]

Afterward the pool is burned out:
[image: Afterward the pool is burned out]

Three men are there:
[image: Three men are there]

They drop a wreath in the pool:
[image: They drop a wreath in the pool]

Comment: Thank you! This has got to be the one. Super Helio Beam not withstanding, I guess it wasn't really a SciFi movie. It is interesting that I remembered it as the woman struggling to hold him, instead of the other way around.